# Server can't find files when htaccess forcefully removes .php from url

Tags: .htaccess

I have managed to make pages work without the php extension but when I click links that have .php, it sends me to the URL with the .php extension.

```
##.php to noindex
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

When I try to forcefully remove it with this, no js or css can be loaded:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: You should make exception for that, i will write something

Comment: Where do you want to go with your htaccess?

Comment: If I click a link, let's say `index.php?page=test` it should go to `index?page=test` (and forcefully remove .php from the address bar) and all js/css should work.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will write something for you

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, it will turn; `page?param=value` into `/page.php?param=value` and it will skip everything with an extension like  `stylesheet.css`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Hope this solves your problem!